# BITCOIND: ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1

Tags: json, json-rpc, bitcoind

I have my Bitcoind server running on `Ubuntu 14.04`. The blocks count is updated and its running well. My problem is that when I access `Bitcoin RPC` using this `curl` command

```
curl --user user_bitcoin:pass_bitcoin --data-binary 
'{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", 
"params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

it returns nothing. When I check debug.log it says:

```
ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1
```

My bitcoin.conf setup is like this

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=<username>
rpcpassword=<password>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure it out.. The problem is that the `bitcoin.conf` file is under the root premises while the `bitcoind` files is on the `ubuntu` premises. So all we need to do is use `chown` to change owner.

This is how I execute the command

`sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu [file..]`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by starting `bitcoind` as follows:

```
$bitcoind -rpcuser=USERNAME -rpcpassword=PASSWORD
```

I was previously getting an error when I started it as:

```
$bitcoind
```